# Clarification about real number axioms

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Similar in spirit to a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754281/ordered-sets-and-the-least-upper-bound), why do we say as part of the axioms for real numbers that: $$\text{"The order relation $<$ has the least upper bound property."}$$ when (presumably) we mean: $$\text{"The set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual order $<$ has the least upper bound property."}$$

To me, it seems wrong or maybe slightly misleading to say the order relation itself has the l.u.b. property since the order relation is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in this case, or a Cartesian product generally.

Is this reasoning correct, and is the original statement essentially an abuse of terminology?

Comment: What's the potential misinterpretation you're worried about?

Comment: @Karl well an order relation on a set $A$ is itself a subset of $A\times A$, so if we say that a subset of $A\times A$ has the least upper bound property...with respect to what order? It wouldn't necessarily be the order relation on $A$ we started with.

Comment: The original statement is not an abuse of terminology. The field of an order can always be recovered from the relation so the least upper bound property of an order on $\Bbb{R}$ is a property of the order as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$. From your comment, you seem to be confusing the subset $<$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$ with $\Bbb{R}^2$ itself.

Comment: We know that the order relation on $\mathbb{R}$ is a total order, meaning that any two distinct elements in $\mathbb{R}$ are related, in particular this means that the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in the projection of $<$ onto either coordinate, so any property of $(\mathbb{R},<)$ can be inferred from $<$ alone, given that $<$ is a total order. Similar to how could deduce any property of a set together with an isomorphism on it, from the isomorphism alone, provided you know that it is an isomorphism. Does that help?

Comment: Where did you see that wording? The way you wrote it is correct. The set of real numbers equipped with the standard order has the least upper bound property.

Comment: @JohnDouma This is from Munkres' Topology text, chapter $1$.

Comment: @RobArthan I think I see what you're saying...because any nonempty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ bounded above is itself a subset of the order relation $<$, which has the l.u.b. property so $A$ must have a l.u.b., so then back again the subset $A$ must have the l.u.b. property?

Comment: @upanddownintegrate I have that book and Munkres definitely defines the least upper bound property on a set. On what page does he say an order relation has the least upper bound property?

Comment: @JohnDouma page $31$

Comment: It's simpler than that: the original statement says that the set is an [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory). An order $R$ is defined relative to a set that can be recovered from $R$ (as the set of all elements that feature on the left or right of a pair in $R$).

Comment: (addendum: I think my argument at the end of one of my previous comments above should have read: "...so then back again $\mathbb{R}$ must have the l.u.b. property." Not the subset $A$.)

Comment: @upanddownintegrate Perhaps I have an older edition. I have "Topology: A first course" published in 1975 and on page 27 he writes "An ordered set is said to have the least upper bound property if every non-empty subset $A_0$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound". That is in section 1.3 Relations.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes I do have the second edition from $2000$, and also that same statement on page $27.$ But on page $31$ in Section $1.4$ in my book he lists as property $7$ of the real numbers that "The order relation $<$ has the least upper bound property." I think the argument for equivalence I've given here in the comments now makes sense to me, and it only relies on knowing that the order $<$ was defined on $\mathbb{R}$ to begin with, as Rob pointed out.

Comment: @upanddownintegrate He takes a shortcut with notation because he supposes a set $R$ on the previous page. All of the properties, including property $7$, are properties of $R$ so, although I agree that he is abusing the language a little, he is saying exactly what you suggested he should say: the set $R$ with order relation $\lt$ has the least upper bound property.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you. Makes sense. Especially now that you point that out on the previous page, I notice he does say "and an order relation $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$". I must have missed that bit.

Comment: Similar to saying "the order relation $<$ has the least upper bound property" without mentioning $\mathbb R$ would be saying "the addition operation $+$ is commutative" without mentioning $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

In your context, the order relation of course is a binary relation, so indeed is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $(\mathbb{R},<)$ has the least upper bound property. It's just a short form to say what you stated in the second centered line.

If we were studying abstract algebra or topology, for instance, where we use less usual sets, and different kind of orders, we clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is implicit in the first.

The first statement is neither wrong nor misleading. Saying that a relation has a property implicitly refers to the set on which the relation is defined.

I would not call it an abuse of terminology.

If you are more comfortable making the set explicit, do that when you write, or fill it in when you read.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right (or at least it's context-dependent). In a set-theoretic context (rather than in the category of sets and relations), you can't determine the intended field from the relation in general, but if you say the relation is an order, you are implying that the intended field can be recovered as the union of the domain and range of the relation and the l.u.b. property is a property of the order alone.

Comment: The order $\lt = \{(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2: a\lt b\}$ is an open half plane. How is that the same thing as $(\mathbb R,\lt)$? I believe @upanddownintegrate is correct.

Comment: @JohnDouma:  no-one is saying that ${<} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$ is the same thing as $(\Bbb{R}, {<})$, but you can recover the latter from the former given the assertion that $<$ is an order, so there is nothing wrong with the original statement.